# Including figures in custom environments.

Tags: floats, environments, mdframed

In my preamble I have the following custom environment that is counted.

```
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
```

When I call this in the text I always write the following piece of code,

```
\begin{exmp}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!20]

Whatever I want to write ... 

\end{mdframed}
\end{exmp}
```

I then wish to enter a figure within this environment.

```
 \begin{exmp}
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!20]

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm, height=5cm]{name-of-figure}
\caption{The caption. }
\label{fig:RC}
\end{figure}

  \end{mdframed}
    \end{exmp}
```

I then get the the following two errors:

```
Latex error: Not in outer par mode. 
Missing number, treated as zero.
```

Everything compiles fine when the code for the figure is removed. Unfortunately the figure really does have to be within the environment. I have absolutely zero idea on how to go about fixing this and appreciate any help you can offer! As an aside I then wish to match the colour of the image to the colour of the mdframed environment, however I have not attempted this yet for obvious reasons!

Comment: ...the `figure` wants to float, while the `mdframed` is preventing it from doing that.

Comment: @Werner Ah it makes sense now! This is despite the "[h!]" as well? Do you know of any remedy to this?

Comment: Change `\begin{figure}` and to `\begin{center}` and likewise for the end of the environment. Load the caption package, and use `\captionof{figure}{Whatever}`.

Comment: the approach that should be used here is addressed in this answer: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39019/579)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The float specifier `[h!]` doesn't guarantee that a float will not move around/stay `h`ere. See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764) for more details.

Moreover, the error "Not in outer par mode" is due to the fact that you are inserting a floating environment inside a container - `mdframed` - that doesn't float. The float has to be placed in a location that is not restricted.

Regardless, you don't need a `figure` (float) environment in order to insert an image. You can just insert it as-is using `\includegraphics`, and use [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)'s `\captionof{figure}` ([`capt-of`](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) provides something similar):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed,xcolor,amsthm,graphicx,caption}

\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{exmp}
  \mbox{}\par
  \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!20]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=8cm, height=5cm]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{The caption.}
  \end{mdframed}
\end{exmp}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This has solved everything, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As Werner said in his comment, `figure` doesn't float. Instead of it inser your image directly in your environment, something like this:

```
 \begin{exmp}
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!20]

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=8cm, height=5cm]{name-of-figure}
\captionof{figure}{The caption. }
\label{fig:RC}
\end{center}

  \end{mdframed}
    \end{exmp}
```

For `captionof` you need package `caption` or if you for it use facility of documentclass, there is also small package `capt-of`.